# Python Regex to look for string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with text that looks like below

> Format={  Window_Type="Tabular",  Tabular={   Num_row_labels=10
>             }
>             }

I need to look for Num_row_labels >=10 in my text file. How do I do that using Python 3.2 regex?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to look for this exact string, or is there any variance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
match = re.search("Num_row_labels=(\d+)", line)
```

The `(\d+)` matches at least one decimal digit (0-9) and captures all digits matched as a group (groups are stored in the object returned by `re.search` and `re.match`, which I'm assigning to `match` here). To access the group and compare compare against `10`, use:

```
if int(match.group(1)) >= 10:
    print "Num_row_labels is at least 10"
```

This will allow you to easily change the value of your threshold, unlike the answers that do everything in the regex. Additionally, I believe this is more readable in that it is very obvious that you are comparing a value against 10, rather than matching a nonzero digit in the regex followed by at least one other digit. What the code above does is ask for the 1st group that was matched (`match.group(1)` returns the string that was matched by `\d+`), and then, with the call to `int()`, converts the string to an integer. The integer returned by `int()` is then compared against 10.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I m literaaly overwhelmed by the # of responses to my question. Python is new to me and regex too. I thought of testing yours first. I m guessting that line in your match = re.search("Num_row_labels=(\d+)", line) would be Format={ Window_Type="Tabular", Tabular={ Num_row_labels=10 } }. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the data is formatted as above, and there is no leading 0's in the number:

```
Num_row_labels=\d{2,}
```

A more liberal regex which allows arbitrary spaces, still assume no leading 0's:

```
Num_row_labels\s*=\s*\d{2,}
```

An even more liberal regex which allows arbitrary spaces, and allow leading 0's:

```
Num_row_labels\s*=\s*0*[1-9]\d+
```

If you need to capture the numbers, just surround `\d{2,}` (in 1st and 2nd regex) or `[1-9]\d+` (in 3rd regex) with parentheses `()` and refers to it in the 1st capture group.

Comment: In a "liberal case" it will work incorrect, e.g. `Num_row_labels=02`

Comment: @IgorChubin: Fixed and tested.

Comment: Thanks nhahtdh! Your solution works well too. I really appreciate all your time and effort in testing out all possible cases to get the best match. :) You ROCK!

Answer (score 0):

the re looks like:

```
Num_row_labels=[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]+
```

Example of usage:

```
if re.search('Num_row_labels=[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]+', line):
   print line
```

The regular expression `[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]+` means that in the string must be at least

- one digit from 1 to 9 (`[1-9]`, symbol class `[]` in regular expressions means that here can be any symbol from the range specified in the brackets);
- and at least one digit from 0 to 9 (but it can be more of them) (`[0-9]+`, the `+` sign in regular expression means that the symbol/expression that stand before it can be repeated 1 or more times).

Before these digits can be any other digits (`[0-9]*`, that means any digit, 0 or more times). When you already have two digits you can have any other digits before — the number would be greater or equal 10 anyway.

Comment: @igor Chubin, i would like to try your fixed version as well. Please kindly help. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: @Nemo By "fixed", he means that he edited his answer to fix it; what you see is the fixed version.

Comment: Thanks Igor Chubin for providing explanation as well. It works well too.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is `Num_row_labels=[1-9][0-9]{1}.*`

Now you can use the `re` python module ([take a look here)](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to analyze your text and extract those

Comment: I would change the `{1}` to `{1,}` to allow numbers higher than 99 and add braces around the numbers to catch them.

Comment: @ManuelFaux : the "1" tells "at least" so this will catch correctly all the numbers. Try it [yourself](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#intro)